# Increase value of several rows based on condition fulfilling all rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns and want to multiply/increase the float numbers of each row by the same amount until the sum of all three cells (one row) fulfils the critera (value equal or greater than 0.9)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.03, 0.0, 0.4],
               'B': [0.1234, 0.4, 0.333],
               'C': [0.5, 0.4, 0.0333]})
```

Outcome:
The different cells in each row were multiplied so that the sum of all three cells of each row is 0.9 (The sum of each row is not exactly 0.9 as I tried to come close with simple multiplication, hence the actual outcome would get to 0.9). It is important that the cells which are 0 would stay 0.

```
print (df)
A         B         C
0  0.0414  0.170292  0.690000
1  0.0000  0.452000  0.452000
2  0.4720  0.392940  0.039294
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to apply a scaling function along the rows:

```
def scale(xs, target=0.9):
    """Scale the features such that their sum equals the target."""
    xs_sum = xs.sum()
    if xs_sum < target:
        return xs * (target / xs_sum)
    else:
        return xs

df.apply(scale), axis=1)
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.03, 0.0, 0.4],
                   'B': [0.1234, 0.4, 0.333],
                   'C': [0.5, 0.4, 0.0333]})
df.apply(scale, axis=1)
```

Should give:

```
          A         B         C
0  0.041322  0.169972  0.688705
1  0.000000  0.450000  0.450000
2  0.469790  0.391100  0.039110
```

The rows of that dataframe all sum to 0.9:

```
df.apply(scale), axis=1).sum(axis=1)

0    0.9
1    0.9
2    0.9
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @ Marijn van Vliet it worked for all the rows that had a sum of less than 0.9 but for the cells that already had a sum of more than 0.9 it also changed them. How could I only do the action for the rows where the columns A,B,C are below 0.9?

Comment: The scaling function can be anything you want. I've updated my answer with a simple if-statement to check whether the sum is below 0.9 (a value provided as a parameter)

Comment: Perfect, that worked. As I am not experienced with scaling could I ask for a last point how to scale only the columns I specify (A to C) as I just realised that I have other columns that I do not want to scale. Thank you

Comment: `df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(scale, axis=1)`

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as such for future readers of your question and my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can take sum on `axis=1` and subtract with 0.9 ,then divide with `df.shape[1]` to add it back:

```
df.add((0.9-df.sum(axis=1))/df.shape[1],axis=0)
```

---

```
         A         B         C
0  0.112200  0.205600  0.582200
1  0.033333  0.433333  0.433333
2  0.444567  0.377567  0.077867
```

Comment: Cell A1 has a value above 0 now (0.333) which I do not want. I was thinking more about a loop that would multiply each row so that the 0 will stay 0.

Comment: I clarified the question slightly: The different cells in each row were multiplied so that the sum of all three cells of each row is 0.9 (The sum of each row is not exactly 0.9 as I tried to come close with simple multiplication, hence the actual outcome would get to 0.9). It is important that the cells which are 0 would stay 0.

Comment: I do not want the cells who are 0 to increase, so the code should multiply instead of add.

Comment: @ManuH what if we exclude 0 from addition? does it neccesarily have to multiply?

Comment: @ anky_91 I am looking for a solution that does multiplication as I would like to increase the bigger values more than the smaller values (see difference between my df and yours after the calculation. Would a loop not work here?

Comment: @ManuH i get it, now, and loops are bad when you have vectorised solutions , probably try with `df.mul(0.9/df.sum(axis=1),axis=0)` . describin specifically the first tme would have avoided these comment chains

Comment: @ anky_91 it worked for all the rows that had a sum of less than 0.9 but for the cells that already had a sum of more than 0.9 it also changed them. How could I only do the action for the rows where the columns A,B,C are below 0.9?

Comment: any chance you could add to the script that the code only modifies the rows where the sum is smaller than 0.9. The other rows should not be changed (and still appear in the output).

Comment: @ManuH I didnt get the question. Also, SO doesnot recommend iterative debugging. If you have a new question, you'd be better of asking a fresh question covering all scenarios. Thanks..!!

Comment: I re-asked the question and gave more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757624/increase-specific-rows-by-multiplication-until-sum-of-columns-fulfils-criteria