# Increase specific rows by multiplication until sum of columns fulfils criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 4 columns and I want to do the following steps (ideally in one code):
- Filter rows where the sum of the 4 columns is lower than 0.9
- Multiply each cell in each row so that the sum of the row is 0.9
- In case there is a 0 in any cell, this cell stays unchanged (as multiplying 0 with anything remains 0)
- At the end display all rows, also the ones that were not changed

Here is an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.03, 0.0, 0.7],
           'B': [0.1234, 0.4, 0.333],
           'C': [0.5, 0.4, 0.0333]})


print (df)
  Name    A    B    C   
0 Bread  0.03 0.1234 0.5000 
1 Butter 0.00 0.4000 0.4000
2 Cheese 0.70 0.3330 0.0333 

Sum = df["A"]+df["B"]+df["C"]
print (Sum)

0    0.6534
1    0.8000
2    1.0663
```

Now only rows 0 and 1 should be affected by the algorithm

I had used this one which worked partly here:

```
df = df4.mul(0.9/df4.sum(axis=1),axis=0)
```

But I do now know how to work only with the columns A to C and how I can first filter by the rows where the sum is below 0.9 and then how to show all rows again.

So my desired outcome is something like this:

```
print (df)
   Name     A         B         C
0  Bread    0.0414  0.170292  0.690000
1  Butter   0.0000  0.452000  0.452000
2  Cheese   0.70    0.3330   0.0333
```

Important, all columns (including product column) and rows should still be there and the format be a dataframe with all of the rows. I only added the sum function below to see that they add up to 0.9 or more.

```
Sum = df["A"]+df["B"]+df["C"]
    print (Sum)

0    0.9
1    0.9
2    1.0663
```

Comment: Do you need the intermediate values of the columns? I mean, if the sum of the row is < 0.9, you simply end with a 0.9, so why not write directly 0.9 instead of do all the calculation to get 0.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the intermediate values in a new dataframe `df2`:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x : x if x.sum() > 0.9 else x.mul(0.9/x.sum()), axis=1)
```

`df2` is:

```
df2
          A         B         C
0  0.041322  0.169972  0.688705
1  0.000000  0.450000  0.450000
2  0.700000  0.333000  0.033300
```

And if you do:

```
df2.sum(axis=1)
```

you get:

```
0    0.9000
1    0.9000
2    1.0663
```

Comment: `m = df.sum(1); np.where(m > 0.9, m, 0.9)`

Comment: @VAlentino Thanks for the answer. But my goal is not only to have the sum of the rows be 0.9 but that the individual numbers still exist and add up to 0.9 together. So ideally the algorithm would know that it needs to multiply each item in row 0 with X and row 1 with Y in order to have their sums be 0.9.

Comment: @ManuH fixed answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### IIUC

```
s = df.sum(1)
df.update(df.div(s / .9, axis=0)[s < .9])

df.sum(1)

0    0.9000
1    0.9000
2    1.0663
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't only want to have the sum of the rows be 0.9 but that the individual numbers still exist and add up to 0.9 together. So ideally the algorithm would know that it needs to multiply each item in row 0 with X and row 1 with Y in order to have their sums be 0.9.

Comment: Please note that I show the sun as proof. The dataframe is as it should be